# Could not find app with bundle id in Nativescript Sidekick

Tags: certificate, nativescript, provisioning, sidekick

When trying to generate a new certificate- and provisioning file in Nativescript Sidekick for an existing app i get the following error:

> An error has occured while generating the certificate and mobile provision. Reason: Could not find app with bundle id., Error: Codesign failed. Reason is: Could not find app with bundle id.
>       at CloudCodesignService. (C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\nativescript-cloud\lib\services\cloud-codesign-service.js:87:29)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at fulfilled (C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\nativescript-cloud\lib\services\cloud-codesign-service.js:4:58)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)

The generation wasn't a problem untill a couple of days ago. I don't have a developer account where i can add the app. The result is that i can't build my demo app for my iphone for test purposes.

Does anyone know a way arround or is this a bug / result of extra check from Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because i had entered my own bundleid and didn't have an account for deploying the app. For development, i switched the name to org.nativescript.MYBUNDLENAME and the bundleid org.nativescript was recognised and i could build again.

For development purposes only, you should register your own bundleid.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the app identifier of your app is already reserved by someone else. To resolve this issue you should modify the Application Identifier of your app to something that is not already reserved.

e.g. 
com.somethingthatmakesyourappidentifieruniqure.myapplication :)

Greetz,

Sascha